# LEX becomes unresponsive when debugging (adding breakpoints) to loaded static resources

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-web-components, javascript-debugging

> Using Chrome - Version 72.0.3626.121

I  often find myself integrating 3rd party libraries and while attempting to do so  in LWC's errors are not uncommon, so, I check the errors and using the browsers dev tools I add some breakpoints to the code in order to try and pinpoint the problem,  however, as soon as I do so and reload the tab, LEX becomes unresponsive =( making debugging/troubleshooting a pain, and it just hangs there and obviosuly, the browser tab becomes unresponsive...

[image]

this happens every single time without fault (when adding a breakpoint to the loaded static resource.

I have yet to test with other browsers such as firefox.

Is this normal in LEX? (i'm assuming I am not the only person affected by this) I was not able to find any Known issues.

> Here is a [gist](http://gist.github.com/gminero/781c18f48239caafd6a01a4eb75986c8) I setup for testing/reproducing the issue:
>    - however, this invovles downloading a framework and uploading it as a static resource to whatever test org you might have. Obviously, you
>   will also need to have the sfdx cli and create a lwc to test.

Comment: Huh, okay, so I can replicate the issue. Maybe the file is just too large to debug? I've never seen this before. Remind me +36 hours, I'll add a bounty if nobody knows what's up.

Comment: if i debug the same either locally or in the context of a web page that is not hosted on salesforce, i dont run into this issue =(

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely odd. I don't have the expertise to debug why this would cause a problem at the browser level, though, so I'll leave it for the experts.

Comment: Do you have plugins installed on Chrome? Do you have a public URL to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I removed all of them and re-tested. Same behavior. gist.github.com/gminero/781c18f48239caafd6a01a4eb75986c8 - however, this invovles downloading a framework and uploading it as a static resource to whatever test org you might have.